# Two routers connected to one modem - Need two isolated networks

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem

My setup is as follows.

```
+-------+
| Modem |
+-------+   
  |  |  |   
  |  |  +----> Internet
  |  |
  |  +-------> Router 1 [192.168.1.1] (Home & Private Network)
  |            |
  |            +---> Main PC & Own Mobile Devices
  |            +---> Lightning
  |            +---> Harmony Hub
  |            +---> Wi-Fi Repeater in Bridge Mode for Living Room Devices (No Repeating)
  |
  +----------> Router 2 [192.168.2.1] (Guest & Testing Network)
               |
               +---> Test & Webbrowsing PC
               +---> Mobile Devices of Friends and Guests
```

Is this setup correct so that the devices connected to router 2 are unable to see/connect to the devices connected to router 1 through my modem? I would like to keep my guest & testing network completely out of my private network.

I already checked and both routers have received different public IPs. Also, when I tried pinging my main pc from my test pc, it timed out as desired. However, when I did it the other way around, I got a message from my ISP "TTL expired in transit". What does that mean exactly? Shouldn't it time out like before?

PS: When I connected router 2 for the first time, its internal IP was also 192.168.1.1 but it worked just fine and there was no IP conflict with router 1. Does this mean they were already isolated from the get go? I changed it to 192.168.2.1 just to be sure.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Although your setup is correct, I wonder what ip addresses your modem provides to both routers, because I think that's where your `TTL expired in transit` message comes from. I bet the modem also has a 192.168.1.x network.

Either put the modem in a different segment, or put router 1's network in a different segment. Given that you already are working with 2 routers, I would suggest 192.168.10.x and 192.168.11.x respectively, keeping the modem at 192.168.1.x, so things remain easy to recognize.

Comment: I think you meant two routers, correct? I only have one modem. Its IP address is 192.168.100.1 actually. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. The two public IPs are very similar btw. The first three segments are the same for both routers. Only the last one differs. For example: Router 1: xx.xxx.xx.yy and Router 2: xx.xxx.xx.zz. This qualifies as different public IPs though, right? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yes, you already mentioned 2 routers and a modem, and I continued on that. But if your modem has the 192.168.100.x segment, then it should all work. the TTL may come from the DNS then. What device is your DNS?

Comment: I was just confused because you said `Given that you already are working with 2 modems`. Anyway, my DNS device is my modem / ISP. I don't use any special DNS service.

Comment: Oh wow. I have read my answer twice, and twice did I failed to see that major typo. Yes of course I meant 2 routers. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

"Request Timed Out" means the computer that sent out the PING did not get any response back.

"TTL Expired in Transit" means a forwarding router along the path responded with an error.

Both, indicate that the Remote host was not reachable. The latter just means that a router along the way decided to tell you so.

It is a little strange to receive the TTL expired message. Likely one of two things are happening:

1. There is an anomaly or misconfiguration in the 192.168.2.1 router. Is it a different model than the other?
2. The modem side is not quite right. I wonder how you are getting 2 public IPs? Most service providers will offer only 1 dynamic public IP unless you are paying for multiple static IPs. If you did purchase static IPs you would normally program them in to each router manually, not use DHCP. So honestly, I think you are getting lucky on that one. This may cause you problems down the road. I wouldn't be surprised if one of your two public IPs is in conflict somewhere in the modem.

Comment: Yes, router 2 is a different model: Netgear WNR3500L v2. Router 1 is a Netgear R6300. I will consult my ISP tomorrow and ask how many public IPs are available for my subscription type and report it back here.

Comment: I finally got an answer! There are 2-3 IP addresses included with my subscription.